# Count rows with the same values from table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have something, and i break my head about it. 
I got a sql statement that select specific rows from my sql database. And i print it out to an html table. This i working fine. 
But i want to count all rows with the same value's.

Here is an example of my Database..

```
ID | Licence_Plate | Driver | Weight 1 | Weight 2 | Company | Date
```

So i wanna count all company's where "Weight 1" greather than 10 000 is..

The output is than:

```
company1 = 5 times overloaded
company2 = 2 times overloaded
company3 = 10 times overloaded
```

I don't know what the beste option is for this. I don't want to use another sql statement because the first sql statement loaded a lot of data in the browser.

Thanks in advance for your opintions.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want a solution in SQL, or PHP, or JS? What have you tried? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: "select * ,count(*) as total from table where  Weight 1 > '10000'";

Comment: I have eddit the question so it is more clear. I prefer php because the output of the sql is verry big.

Answer (score 0):

Put the rows in a json Array for example

```
var jsonArray=[{id:1,License_plate:"xyz",Driver:"driver1",weight1:2,weight2:30,company:"abc",data:"29 Dec 2009"},{}.....]
```

then use the below option for filter:

```
jsonArray.filter(function(option){
    return option.weight1>10000
})
```